# MediaMetadata.getString java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read bitmap from parcel blob

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-music-player

Call MediaMetadata.getString, have below crash in report, but not always repro:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read bitmap from parcel blob.
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreateFromParcel(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.access$000(Bitmap.java:32)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap$1.createFromParcel(Bitmap.java:1477)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap$1.createFromParcel(Bitmap.java:1469)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2246)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2146)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2479)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.getCharSequence(BaseBundle.java:953)
    at android.os.Bundle.getCharSequence(Bundle.java:716)
    at android.media.MediaMetadata.getText(MediaMetadata.java:334)
    at android.media.MediaMetadata.getString(MediaMetadata.java:347)
```

The code is as blow, the MediaMetadata meta is from the controller of api MediaSessionManager.OnActiveSessionsChangedListener, it should be created by third-part music app.

```
    meta.getString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ARTIST);
    meta.getString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);            
    meta.getString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_AUTHOR);         
    meta.getBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ART);
    meta.getBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART);            
    meta.getString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
    meta.getString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

Why the getString will parse the bitmap? is it possible the memory is out when this happen?

Comment: What field are you reading / how are you constructing the `MediaMetadata`?

Comment: add the detail @ianhanniballake

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: @SarahMa can you fix it? i have a same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens when you put big bitmaps into the `MediaMetaData` object with `.putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON, icon)`. This bitmap is used on the `MediaDescription` and thus it should be pretty small as it's serialized. It's actually deserialized every time you call `getString` on the meta data.

So, the solution to this issue would be to only use small bitmaps for `METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON` or not use it at all if possible.